# A problem based on kinematics and hinges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]

Four identical rods are hinged at their ends to make a parallelogram ABCD. The hinged joint A is rigidly attached to a wall and the opposite joint C is pulled away from the wall with a constant acceleration a. Initially, the joints A and C were coincident. Find acceleration vector of the joint B at the instant shown

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you